# Ruby: How to load a file into interactive ruby console (IRB)?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am using IRB (interactive ruby console) to learn how to program with Ruby. How do I load a file into the console if I write my programs in a text editor first?

Comment: Is [this][1] what you want to achieve ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2652558/919641

Comment: source("filename.rb")

Answer (score 104):

If you only need to load one file into IRB you can invoke it with `irb -r ./your_file.rb` if it is in the same directory.

This automatically requires the file and allows you to work with it immediately.

Comment: If you want to add more than just -r between each file, well that's what I do and it works. It's how I load all my files into irb so I can access all my app's stuff within irb, of course I use a rake script to load the boot file into irb so I can just `rake irb` and it does it all for me.

Comment: this was my first attempt after reading man, but i use -r some_file.rb, 30 minutes later i found this and add ./, thanks xd

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, I remove the dot: `irb -r /foo/foo.rb`

Comment: This doesn't give access to variables from the file.

Answer (score 58):

Using ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04, I am able to load files from the current directory into `irb` with the following command line:

```
irb -I . -r foo.rb
```

where `foo.rb` is the file I want to load from my current directory. The `-I` option is necessary to add the current directory (`.`) to ruby's load path, as explained in the ruby man page. This makes it possible to `require` files from the current directory, which is what the `-r` option to `irb` accomplishes.

The key piece that wasn't obvious for me when I had this problem is the `-I` option. Once you do that, you can call `require 'foo.rb'` from within `irb` for any files in the current directory. And of course, you can specify any directory you want, not just `.` with the `-I` option. To include multiple directories on the load path, separate them with a colon (:), e.g.:

```
irb -I foo/:bar/:baz/
```

This command will add the directories `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` to ruby's load path.

The final alternative is to use the relative or absolute path to the file when using `require` or `-r` to load a file:

```
irb -r ./foo.rb
```

or from within `irb`:

```
> require './foo.rb'
```

Comment: The result of your solution is the same as calling 'ruby foo.rb', but at least you see what is going on. But I want to leave the console open, so I can execute some more commands. Any idea?

Answer (score 39):

Type in `irb`

And then

```
require './ruby_file.rb'
```

This is assuming that ruby_file.rb is in the same directory. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: You can also use `require_relative`. E.g. `require "./lib/foo"` does the same as `require_relative "lib/foo"`

Comment: `.rb` is optional, you can write `require './ruby_file'. I checked in `ruby 1.9.3p551`

Comment: what does the ./ do?

Comment: @the12 it's a relative path to the current directory

Answer (score 33):

Two ways:

1. to load source *without* running the program -- this gives access to all variables and functions:

`source("filename.rb")`

2. to run program and then drop into interactive mode -- this only gives access to functions, not variables:

`require("filename.rb")`

Comment: This appears to answer the question, how to reload a script as well. I had been using `require` which doesn't appear to reload the script (any modifications to original source are not reflected in your session), while `source` appears to reflect changes to original script.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your ruby.  Ruby 1.8 includes your current path, while ruby 1.9 does not.  Evaluate `$:` to determine if your path is included or not.  So in ruby 1.9 you must use the entire path, which is always a safe bet.

Then you can use `require` or `load` to include the file.

`require` does not require you to add the suffix of the file when trying to find it and will only include the file once.  `require` should be used instead of `load` most of the time.

Check out [Adding a directory to $LOAD_PATH (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837123/adding-a-directory-to-load-path-ruby) if you are going to be using ruby 1.8

Answer (score 2):

Type the ruby codes in the text editor

Save it with the extension **.rb** (for example: **demo.rb**).

In linux, open your terminal then change directory to the current location of that file (cd command is used to change directory).

After that,type irb and your filename(don't forget to include your extension(.rb)).

[image: click here to see loading a ruby file using irb]

In that image,I loaded a simple ruby file which only prints "ruby".

Comment: Good answer, but I suggest posting the terminal session as [text rather than an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1):

For those, who want to load .rb file from the different directory. Just add a string representer of the directory to $: variable.

```
> $: << "/directory/to/the/required/rb/file"
> require "file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to load the path into irb is just type require then drag and drop the file into the terminal.
-tested using Linux Mint.