# Executing a ruby script on Windows 7 command line with multiple ruby files required

Tags: ruby, windows, file, batch-file, require

This might be a trivial question, but I've searched and found nothing about it. I'm trying to make a complex application on ruby and I have my classes on different .rb files which the "Main" class requires. As it's written in the code:

```
require 'Book.rb'
require 'Person.rb'
```

These files that contains the classes are in the same directory, so what I'm looking for is a Batch command which allows me to include these files, like the one for one file but extended:

```
ruby Main.rb
```

Which, of course fails saying that it can't find 'Book.rb' (returns error and doesn't look for the other)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112245/how-do-you-load-a-file-into-interactive-ruby-console) may help

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for that. Finally it worked with irb -I . -r Main.rb

Comment: Welcome :-). You can accept your answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't until 2 days, but I'll do ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user Abhi y found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112245/how-do-you-load-a-file-into-interactive-ruby-console) post. The command that worked for me was:

```
irb -I . -r Main.rb
```

From which you can get further information on the link.